# in polars, how could i use rank() to get most popular category per user

Tags: python-polars

Let's say I have a csv

```
transaction_id,user,book
1,bob,bookA
2,bob,bookA
3,bob,bookB
4,tim,bookA
5,lucy,bookA
6,lucy,bookC
7,lucy,bookC
8,lucy,bookC
```

per user, i want to find the book they have shown the most preference towards. For example, the output should be;

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌──────┬──────────┐
│ user ┆ fav_book │
│ ---  ┆ ---      │
│ str  ┆ str      │
╞══════╪══════════╡
│ bob  ┆ bookA    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ tim  ┆ bookA    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ lucy ┆ bookC    │
└──────┴──────────┘
```

now i've worked out how to do it like so

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.read_csv("book_aggs.csv")

print(df)

df2 = df.groupby(["user", "book"]).agg([
  pl.col("book").count(),
  pl.col("transaction_id") # just so we can double check where it all came from - TODO: how to output this to csv?
  ])

print(df2)

df3 = df2.sort(["user", "book_count"], reverse=True).groupby("user").agg([
  pl.col("book").first().alias("fav_book")
])

print(df3)
```

but really the normal sql way of doing it is a dense_rank sorted by book count descending where rank = 1. I have tried for hours to get this to work but i can't find a relevant example in the docs.

the issue is that in the docs, none of the agg examples reference the output of another agg - in this case it needs to reference the count of each book per user, and then sort those counts descending and then rank based on that sort order.

Please provide an example that explains how to use rank to perform this task, and also how to nest aggregations efficiently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Approach 1

We could first group_by `user` and 'book' to get all `user -> book` combinations and count the most occurring.

This would give this intermediate `DataFrame`:

```
shape: (5, 3)
┌──────┬───────┬────────────┐
│ user ┆ book  ┆ book_count │
│ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---        │
│ str  ┆ str   ┆ u32        │
╞══════╪═══════╪════════════╡
│ lucy ┆ bookC ┆ 3          │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ lucy ┆ bookA ┆ 1          │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ bob  ┆ bookB ┆ 1          │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ tim  ┆ bookA ┆ 1          │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ bob  ┆ bookA ┆ 2          │
└──────┴───────┴────────────┘
```

Then we can do another group_by `user` where we compute the index of the `maximum` `book_count` and use that index to `take` the correct `book`.

The whole query looks like this:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({'book': ['bookA',
          'bookA',
          'bookB',
          'bookA',
          'bookA',
          'bookC',
          'bookC',
          'bookC'],
 'transaction_id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 'user': ['bob', 'bob', 'bob', 'tim', 'lucy', 'lucy', 'lucy', 'lucy']
})

(df.group_by(["user", "book"])
 .agg([
     pl.col("book").count()
 ])
 .group_by("user")
 .agg([
     pl.col("book").gather(pl.col("book_count").arg_max()).alias("fav_book")
 ])
)
```

And creates this output:

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌──────┬──────────┐
│ user ┆ fav_book │
│ ---  ┆ ---      │
│ str  ┆ str      │
╞══════╪══════════╡
│ tim  ┆ bookA    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ bob  ┆ bookA    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ lucy ┆ bookC    │
└──────┴──────────┘
```

### Approach 2

Another approach would be creating a `book_count` column with a `window_expression` and then use the index of the maximum to `take` the correct book in aggregation:

```py
(df
 .with_columns(pl.count("book").over(["user", "book"]).alias("book_count"))
 .group_by("user")
 .agg([
     pl.col("book").gather(pl.col("book_count").arg_max())
 ])
)
```

Comment: I've run the same thing and the output is random for me - how does the rank know to sort by highest book count? quite often bob is bookB - i'm assuming the answers i get is because of how the rank is spread across cores

Comment: You are right, I've restored my first answer.

Comment: amazing, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

[`.mode()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.mode.html#polars.Expr.mode) has since been added to Polars for this.

```py
df.group_by("user").agg(pl.col("book").mode())
```

```py
shape: (3, 2)
┌──────┬───────────┐
│ user ┆ book      │
│ ---  ┆ ---       │
│ str  ┆ list[str] │
╞══════╪═══════════╡
│ bob  ┆ ["bookA"] │
│ tim  ┆ ["bookA"] │
│ lucy ┆ ["bookC"] │
└──────┴───────────┘
```